# Dynamic Linq Where with Lambda Expression generates Error

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dynamic Linq query

```
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereHelper<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string property, string propertyValue) where T : class
    {
        //STEP 1: Verify the property is valid
        var searchProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(property);
         //STEP 2: Create the OrderBy property selector
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");

        MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
        MethodCallExpression queryExpr = Expression.Call(member, method, constant);
                    
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), property);

        MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new Type[] { source.ElementType },
        source.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(queryExpr, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCallExpression);
    }
```

This function generates an error which is the following:

> No generic method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is
> compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type
> arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

An idea on the error, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `Func<T, bool>` because the predicate for `Where` method is a function to test each element for a condition and type of input elements is `T` while the output is `bool`.

Finally, when creating the lambda expression, pass the same parameter used in `queryExpr`, otherwise it'd raise error variable not found. So instead of `pe`, it is `parameter`.

```cs
MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
  typeof(Queryable),
  "Where",
  new Type[] { source.ElementType },
  source.Expression,
  Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
      queryExpr, 
      new ParameterExpression[] { parameter }
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, it is working,can you tell me please how can i add "Or" statement to this generated function, that let me to use this function for searching by multiple columns.

Comment: Please create a new question and include the code you have so far.